# Grep expression with spaces - BASH

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to grep `ACCEPT, DROP, REJECT` as is shown below.

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT DROP
-P FORWARD REJECT
```

I executed

`iptables -S | grep -E '\-P INPUT|\-P OUTPUT|\-P FORWARD' | awk '{print $2}'`

My output looks like this

```
INPUT
OUTPUT
FORWARD
```

Anybody know how to grep only `ACCEPT, DROP, REJECT`? I just want grep policy in built-in chains. Below built-in chains I got user's chains which **cannot** be connected to result.

Thank you,
M

Comment: Change your `awk` `$2` to `$3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. If you need the whole line:

```
iptables -S | grep -- "-P" | grep -E "ACCEPT|DROP|REJECT"
```

Output

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT DROP
-P FORWARD REJECT
```

---

If you need only the matching words:

```
iptables -S | grep -- "-P" | grep -oE "ACCEPT|DROP|REJECT"
```

Output

```
ACCEPT
DROP
REJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to invoke `grep` if `awk` is involved anyway:

```
iptables -S | 
  awk '/^-P INPUT/ {INPUT=$3}; /^-P FORWARD/ {FORWARD=$3}; /^-P OUTPUT/ {OUTPUT=$3}; 
  END {print INPUT; print FORWARD; print OUTPUT;}'
```